# Deuteronomy 21:3 Who is supposed to finance the heifer?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 21

> <sup>**1**</sup>If one is found slain, lying in a field in the land that the LORD your God is giving you to possess, and it is not known who killed him, <sup>**2**</sup>your elders and judges must come out and measure the distance from the victim to the neighboring cities.
>
> <sup>**3**</sup>Then the elders of the city nearest the victim shall take a heifer that has never been yoked or used for work, <sup>**4**</sup>bring the heifer to a valley with running water that has not been plowed or sown, and break its neck there by the stream.

Who is paying for the heifer?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context, since it is "the elders" who must bring the heifer, the responsibility falls on them.

> And it shall be, that the city which is next unto the slain man, even
> **the elders of that city shall take an heifer**, which hath not been
> wrought with, and which hath not drawn in the yoke; (Deuteronomy 21:3,
> KJV)

If the city had some form of government in which all citizens contributed to the city's expenses, the burden might be shared more widely.  But from the text itself, the best we might conclude is that it is up to the elders themselves.  (It would be rather difficult to offer a heifer which one did not first own, and it is the elders who are commanded to offer it.)

Answer (score 0):

Gill explains:

> even the elders of the city shall take an heifer; of a year old, as the same **Targum**, and so **Jarchi**; and in this the Jewish writers agree, that it must be a year old, but not two

It is supported by Targum and Jarchi.

Jamieson-Fausset-Brown provides the logistical detail:

> According to Jewish writers, the **Sanhedrin**, taking charge of such a case,
> sent a deputation to examine the neighborhood.

The Sanhedrin representative oversaw the local logistics.

> They reported to the nearest town to the spot where the body was found. An order was then issued by their supreme authority to the **elders or magistrates** of that town, to provide the heifer at the **civic expense** and go through the appointed ceremonial. The engagement of the public authorities in the work of expiation, the **purchase** of the victim heifer, the conducting it to a "rough valley" which might be at a considerable distance, and which, as the original implies, was a wady, a perennial stream, in the waters of which the polluting blood would be wiped away from the land, and a desert withal, incapable of cultivation; the washing of the hands, which was an ancient act symbolical of innocence—the whole of the ceremonial was calculated to make a deep impression on the Jewish, as well as on the Oriental, mind generally; to stimulate the activity of the magistrates in the discharge of their official duties; to lead to the discovery of the criminal, and the repression of crime.

Who was supposed to finance the heifer in Deuteronomy 21:3?

The local government was supposed to and the affair was overseen by the Sanhedrin.